# A question about the index of the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ . We say the nonnegative integer number $k$ to be the
index of matrix $A$, if $k$ is the smallest nonnegative integer number such that

$rank(A^{k+1}) = rank(A^{k})$......$(1)$

Based on the definition $(1)$ could we conclude that $R(A^{k+1}) =R(A^{k})$, where $R(A)$, denote the range space of the matrix $A$.?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $R(A^{k+1})\subseteq R(A^k)$--consider dimensions.

EDIT: Also, why is this number useful? It's the size of the largest Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$ for $A$, but besides that, I don't see its use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we consider dimensions then $dim(R(A^{k+1}) = dim R(A^{k})$ , by definition and hence $R(A^{k+1}) =R(A^{k})$. Am i right? Thanks

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. In fact in terms of null space also you can define. There are many other equivalent definitions for index of a matrix over a field. Index helps to characterize that matrix and hence it has so many applications. For more details you can refer Generalized inverses by Adi Ben-Israel and Greville.